# Unable to login into Kupiki captive portal using the given username and password(Raspberry Pi 3 B+)

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, login, hotspot

I tried to create a captive portal for my Raspberry Pi's Wifi hotspot using Kupiki-Hotspot-Script which is given in this link
[Kupiki-Hotspot-Script](https://github.com/pihomeserver/Kupiki-Hotspot-Script)

However I am unable to login using the given Username and Password. It says Username or Password incorrect. What is the correct Username and password for Kupiki-Hotspot-Script and how do I change it?

Comment: right at the end of the script it tells you `user:administrator, password:radius` - did you try that?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But it does not work. @JaromandaX